# Docker Error - 5432: bind: address already in use

Tags: postgresql, macos, docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I used to be able to run docker-compose using 5432:5432 port mapping, but am recently getting this error:

```
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use
```

I've gone through all of the older posts relating to this issue but have yet to be able to solve this.

I've been driving myself mad with this error for the past week trying to figure out how to stop whatever process is running with no avail.

I've tried running

```
lsof -i tcp:5432
```

which returns no results (as long as my pgadmin/server is not running)

I've also seen other posts mention running

```
netstat -anp tcp | grep 5432
```

which *does* return two lines:

```
tcp4       0      0  *.5432                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  *.5432                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

But I'm not entirely sure what to do with that output?

Answer (score 14):

Run `lsof -i tcp:5432` with sudo rights:

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:5432
```

A process (very likely PostgreSQL) is listening on port 5432, preventing another to listen on that port. Stop the process, e.g. with `systemctl`, then you will be able to start your docker PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks - so this does return two results - do I then need to kill those two PID's and try again? I don't for the life of me know where this would be running - pgadmin is shut down, the server is off, and I don't have any containers running. I should add I tried running kill -9 <pid> but got "operation not permitted" error

Comment: You can kill the process via sudo kill [-9] <pid> (although it would be better to use the process manager on your system, e.g. systemd). But the problem will likely reoccur after the next reboot, assuming that a PostgreSQL process is started automatically.

Comment: I see - is the best move to just use a different port if that is the case?

Comment: Of course that's possible but that would mean every application wanting to connect to your docker PostgreSQL must explicitly use this non-default port.

Comment: In that case is there any way to find out what resource might be using that port upon startup every time, and eliminate it from happening further? Have I essentially done something wrong to cause this to happen? Even using the sudo kill -9, two new processes appear each time I kill one

Comment: Of course there is. How you control that depends on your process manager. I assume on MacOS there is also a GUI allowing you to configure that.

Comment: Why port 80? Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that this might be happening due to multiple instances of postgres running on your machine.

In my case, I had previously installed postgres which was always running on the machine because of which docker-based postgres was unable to start due to the above error. Uninstalling previously installed postgres helped to resolve the issue.